# Jquerymobile Panel

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile

I have a question about Panel Widget in jquery mobile. I want to add classes to the overlay on the page to dismiss the panel when hidden (Link to docs: [Link](https://api.jquerymobile.com/panel/#option-classes.modal)).
In javascript I can do something like:

```
$("#id").panel("option", "classes", "modal", "customClass ui-panel-dismiss" );
```

But this is not working. If I add this, the panel don't show again. So anyone know how to do this in html attributes with data-...?

EDIT: with the event onclick to show the panel I added:

```
$(".ui-panel-dismiss").addClass("custClass");
```

This works fine, but is there any other way?